# Script to check Computer Model and Download BIOS File

Tags: windows, batch, script, download

I've just started working with WindowsScripting and would like some help figuring out how to write a Script that would check the model of a Computer and store the result in Variable in the Bat file.

Ultimately I am trying to automate checking the Computer model and download the correct BIOS file.

Here's what I've got so far.

```
start "" wmic computersystem get model > model.txt
if model == X
  start "" %windir%\explorer.exe "download url"
elseif model == Y
  start "" %windir%\explorer.exe "download url"
elseif model == Z
  start "" %windir%\explorer.exe "download url"
```

Any help is appreciated as I am new to this whole thing.

Comment: To the close voters: 1/ question is **not** off-topic, batch files are on-topic for [su] 2/ it's perfectly clear what he is asking (see my answer)

Comment: Shouldn't be closed, but doesn't sound like the best idea... I wouldn't want to update my BIOS without carefully reading the release notes, and making absolutely 100% sure I get the correct update file. Most BIOS update info I've read (from the manufacturers) say "If you don't need it, and if it ain't broke, don't fix it"

Comment: Two people have voted to close this, but I can't see why. The question is clear: OP wants to get the computer model and branch on it.

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I set the result of the following command to be a variable called model?

```
wmic computersystem get model
```

The output of this on my system is:

```
Model
VPCF22L1E
```

Note the extra blank line. I've used `VPCF22L1E` to test the batch file.

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq skip=1" %%i in (`wmic computersystem get model`) do (
  set model=%%i
  goto :done
  )
:done
if [%model%]==[VPCF22L1E] start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "download url for VPCF22L1E"
if [%model%]==[Y] start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "download url for Y"
if [%model%]==[Z] start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "download url for Z"
endlocal
```

Notes:

- `skip=1` is used to skip the `wmic` header line.
- `goto :done` is use to skip the `wmic` extra blank line.
- Edit the `if` lines as appropriate.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window).
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: Thank you David! I really appreciate the help and the fact that you not only explained what you did but also provided further reading material! Thank you very much!

Comment: @babsndeep Do you need more help? If this answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept that answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer). Also see [Why is voting important?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: Hey David, Yes! what you provided was very helpful, Sorry I didn't know about the Voting!.However, I  was working on the rest of the script today and tested this code alone in a separate file, and couldn't get it to work.                                                                                                 @echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq skip=1" %%i in ('wmic computersystem get model') do (
 set model=%%i
 goto :done
 )
:done
if [%model%]==[Latitude E6320] start "" %windir%\explorer.exe http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER03279939M/1/E6330A15.exe    endlocal

Comment: The output of 'wmic get computersystem model' is: Model                                                          Latitude E6320

Comment: That should work. What is the output from `wmic computersystem get model` on your PC?

Comment: Can you add `echo %model%` after the `set` and tell me what it outputs?

Comment: Model    (on first line)                                                                                              Latitude E6320 (on second line)                                                                       When I run 'wmic get computersystem model' in cmd directly

Comment: It could be because of the space in the model name. Try changing `usebackq skip=1` to `usebackq skip=1 tokens=*`

Comment: No Change with tokens=* addition

Comment: Please add the `echo %model%` as I requested.

Comment: I did add echo %model%, the cmd window flashes really quick, I am not unable to read anything from it.

Comment: Add `pause` as the next line

Comment: Note, I couldn't get it to work with `%windir%\explorer.exe` thats why I changed the batch file to use `%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` instead.

Comment: %ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer \iexplorer.exe doesn't work for me, even when run as a standalone command in cmd window, %windir%\explorer.exe does however work when run alone in the cmd window.

Comment: <shrug> I've done my best. It works here as described on Windows 7. Don't forget to add quotes around `"%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"` as it contains a space.